# No tick on breakpoint in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

so I'm trying to debug a project (written in c) with eclipse. I added the project with the "makefile project with existing code" option and entered the location of the source-code. Also I chose Linux GCC.

When I click on the debug-button, the code starts to run and I get all the output I'm expecting. But I can't use breakpoints. When I add a breakpoint, the little tick next to the blue dot is missing. I've read that this means that "the source code differs from byte code". I just don't know what to do with this information.

The application I entered in the "debug configurations" was created by the source-code. And it should contain debug-information.

Also, I'm getting two other error-messages:

- when I start the debugging, a window appears saying "No source available for "main() at 0x404280"" -> I spend a lot of time in different threads researching solutions for that message but none of them worked for me. But if I click "Resume", the code starts running... So I'm not sure whether there is a problem with the source-code.
- In the error-tab it says "program "g++" not found in path" -> Again I spend a lot of time researching. Some people in the internet say to just ignore that message.

So I don't know whether these two error-messages are relevant to my problem.

I'd appreciate any suggestions of what I could do.